# android app error: application has stopped unexpectely, try again doesn't even start the app

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was editing anandroid app that was based off of a similar one I had done before that had worked before. This time its not working but I don't know why.

App error:

```
The Application Buchanan Java Quiz Game (process hu.csc395.javaquizgame) has stopped unexpectedly Please Try again.
```

My log shows this:

```
04-28 04:31:40.326: D/AndroidRuntime(337): Shutting down VM
04-28 04:31:40.326: W/dalvikvm(337): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x40015560)
04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{hu.csc395.javaquizgame/hu.csc395.javaquizgame.Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity}:    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I don't know where these are located so maybe I'm just missing it.

Full Logcat with the exception:

```
    04-28 04:31:40.326: D/AndroidRuntime(337): Shutting down VM
    04-28 04:31:40.326: W/dalvikvm(337): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hu.csc395.javaquizgame/hu.csc395.javaquizgame.Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:186)   
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at hu.csc395.javaquizgame.Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity.resetQuiz(Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity.java:121)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at hu.csc395.javaquizgame.Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity.onCreate(Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity.java:85)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
   04-28 04:31:40.395: E/AndroidRuntime(337):   ... 11 more
   04-28 04:34:37.995: I/Process(337): Sending signal. PID: 337 SIG: 9
```

And my console shows everything running normally until:

```
  [2012-04-28 01:48:17 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-04-28 01:48:17 - Buchanan_JavaQuizGame] New emulator found: emulator-5554
```

Comment: Add the `FULL` exception stacktrace from the `Logcat`.

Comment: how do i do that without filling up the page

Comment: Add all the error lines(the red colored ones from `Logcat`), it doesn't matter how big is that. You have an `IllegalArgumentException` throw somewhere in your code and I would like to see what is it and where it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you use the `nextInt` method of the `Random` class and I think you pass it a negative `integer` and this will throw the `IllegalArgumentException`(it requires that the method parameter is positive).

This happens in your `resetQuiz` method so check there what you do in your code.

Comment: I see at least 4 places where I use random.nextInt I'm not sure where the error is?

Comment: @GabrielleBuchanan Check line `121` in the class `Buchanan_JavaQuizGameActivity`.

Comment: int numberOfFlags = fileNameList.size(); 
      while (flagCounter <= 10)
      {
   int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfFlags); 
   //get the random file name
   String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);
   
   if (!quizJavaList.contains(fileName))
   {
    quizJavaList.add(fileName); // add the file to the list
    ++flagCounter;
   } 
  } 
  loadNextFlag();
 }

Comment: @GabrielleBuchanan I guess line `121` is `int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfFlags);`. Could it be that `numberOfFlags` is `0`?(this will throw the exception). Put the line `Log.v("VVV", "Number of flags is: " + numberOfFlags);` after int `numberOfFlags = fileNameList.size();` and see what it says in the `Logcat`.

Comment: it is possible that the numberOfFlags is 0

Comment: @GabrielleBuchanan Well, if that `numberOfFlags` is `0` then the `nextInt()` method will throw the `IllegalArgumentException` because the number it receives is expected to be greater than `0`. The solution is to make sure that you don't pass `0` to `nextInt()`.

Comment: here is the code that assigns numbers to the numberOfFlag      private void resetQuiz()
 {
  
  AssetManager assets = getAssets(); 
  fileNameList.clear(); // empty the list
  try
  {
   Set<String> regions = sectionsMap.keySet(); 
   
   for (String region : regions)
   {
    if (sectionsMap.get(region)) // if region is enabled
    {
     
     String[] paths = assets.list(region);
     for (String path : paths)
      fileNameList.add(path.replace(".png", ""));
    } } }

Comment: @GabrielleBuchanan Sorry I can't help you because I don't see your full code/assets etc. My advice is: you either debug the app step by step and see why `fileNameList` is `0`(if you expect its size to not be `0` at all times) or you add an extra check and make sure you don't call `nextInt`(an other `nextInt` calls) when the number you supply to it is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to there are two emulators open at the same time.